# Why does this not evaluate in Scheme?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, expression, lisp, racket

I am using the DrRacket environment to try out the Scheme language.

I defined sum+1 as follows:

```
(define sum+1 '(+ x y 1))
```

I was wondering why the following expression does not evaluate:

```
(let ([x 1] [y 2]) (eval sum+1))
```

whereas doing this returns the correct value:

```
(define x 1)
(define y 2)
(eval sum+1)
```

Comment: This is explained reasonably well [in the Racket guide](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/eval.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eval` does not work with lexical variables at all unless the lexical variable was created in the same expression:

```
#!r7rs 
(import (scheme base)
        (scheme eval))

(define env (environment '(scheme base)))

(let ((x 10))
  (eval 'x env)) ; ERROR! `x` is not defined
```

You can think of it as `eval` always happening top level with the global bindings of the environment you pass to the second argument. You can perhaps trick it by passing values from your lexical environment like this:

```
(eval '(let ((x 10))
         x)
      env) ; ==> 10


(let ((x 10))
  (eval `(let ((x ,x))
           x)
        env) ; ==> 10
```

By the time most Scheme implementations run code local variables are usually stack allocated. Thus something imagine this code:

```
(define (test v)
  (display v)
  (newline)
  (eval 'v))
```

Might turn into this at runtime:

```
(define (test 1 #f) ; indicates 1 argument, no rest
  (display (ref 0)) ; fetches first argument from stack
  (newline)
  (eval 'v))        ; but what is v?, certainly not the first argument
```

Also you can make corner cases. What happens if you mutate?

```
(define (test v)
  (eval '(set! v 10))
  v)
```

The structure to `eval` might come from user input so it's not obvious that `v` gets mutated, also many compiling Scheme implementations need to treat variables that mutate differently so it needs to know before the code runs that `v` needs special treatment, but it is not decidable because the `(set! v 10)` might come from the database or user input. Thus by not including local bindings you save yourself a lot of trouble and the language gets easier to optimize and compile.

There are lisp languages that can only be interpreted since it allows for passing macros as first class objects. These languages are impossible to reason about at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the command with `let` does not work is that `let` creates *local variables*. This means that the variables it creates can NOT be accessed from just anywhere - only from within `let`'s body argument.

In your example, you defined:

```
(define sum+1 '(+ x y 1))
```

Then you commanded this:

```
(let ([x 1] [y 2]) (eval sum+1))
```

This doesn't work because `x` and `y` are only being defined in the `eval` statement, not within the procedure `sum+1`. This may seem counter-intuitive, but it prevents many errors with other inputs.

Your second example was:

```
(define x 1)
(define y 2)
(eval sum+1)
```

This does works because `x` and `y` are defined *globally*. This means that they CAN be accessed anywhere, and by anything. They are then applied to the `sum+1` definition and are able to be printed. Please respond with any questions or feedback you have!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, so 'eval' can't see the definitions in the scope where it is called but only the ones in the global scope. I find this behavior strange because other procedures can access the local scope which overrides the global one, and as eval itself is a procedure and not a special form it should behave like all other procedures!  Is there a reason that justifies this behavior?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure as to why eval doesn't behave like other procedures, but here's my best guess: eval is a specific function asking for something to be evaluated, so it is possible that instead of asking (like other functions do), "What information is _available_ to me to solve this problem?" it asks, "What information is _being given_ to me to solve this problem?" meaning, it needs specific instructions given to it as opposed to a procedure that is called globally. (Sorry if that didn't make a lot of sense, it sounded reasonable in my head.)

Comment: It's worth thinking about how an implementation where `eval` *could* see lexical bindings would work: in particular how should `(eval (read))` work?  How would a compiler work?